# Remove Web Developer and use regular Firefox

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

I can't kill the Web Developer Edition on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I really want to because it is not playing well with Google Hangouts which I have to use for work.  Can you help?

Comment: You could use their browser, it should play well together.

Comment: i try but web developer takes over and the issue is that it is not working with the hangouts due to a 32 versus 64 bit software error...